# Where and how do some folders on the server get converted into URL adresses?

Tags: html, sql-server, wordpress

Where and how do some folders on the server get converted into URL adresses? For example, how does my wordpress folder called `wp-admin` on the root folder of the server becomes `http://mysite.com/wp-admin` ? Does it happen within the database or within the html code or elsewhere?

Comment: Definitely not within the database (job of the database is to deal with data strictly). Its part of the way IIS or apache work, they are web enabled folders.  So your site may have folders within it that can be browsed.

Comment: 1. Folders on server don't exists. They never did!
2. I guess its called [.htaccess](http://davidwalsh.name/wordpress-htaccess)

Comment: Which WebServer do you use, as the answer is distinct for each one. e.g. Apache, IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens in the web server configuration.  For apache, there is a variable called `DocumentRoot` .  Any file or directory under this directory will be available to your web server.  For example, if your `DocumentRoot` is `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs`, then `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/foo` will be seen as `http://mysite.com/foo` .